# Posgres Posgis query ignoring geo index on order by

Tags: postgresql, indexing

We have a table full of property locations which, when queried against an area polygon, returns the results very, very fast (by using the correct lonlat index)

BUT... when we include an additional "order by" parameter on a different attribute (price, which also has its own index) then postgres decides to privilege the price index over the lonlat one, and the query runs several 1000 times slower.

- Is there a way to use both indexes?
- If not, how can we explain to postgres that it's choosing the wrong one?

Interestingly, we have tried removing the price index altogether and the query then goes back to the lonlat index and runs very fast. Unfortunately the price index is essential in other parts of the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to say about planning errors like these.

First, PostgreSQL could use both indexes but he chooses not to for some reason. Maybe the cost of fetching both index pages + fetching data pages is prohibitively bad.

Beside that, he picked a really bad plan, so you need to check the expected vs actual row count with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. If PostgreSQL is wrong about the various row counts, you might need to refresh his table statistics with a `VACUUM ANALYZE`. 
If this still doesn't change the query plan, you might consider tweaking [the statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) (getting more infos about a column might do the trick)

But in the end you can always trick PostgreSQL to do what you want with CTEs.
[Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) are, as stated in the documentation, "optimisation fences". This means that PostgreSQL will not try to rewrite a sub query using CTE.

If your fast query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM gis_table
WHERE /* some latlong filter */
```

And your slow query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM gis_table
WHERE /* some latlong filter */
ORDER BY price
```

You can force PostgreSQL behaviour with

```
WITH filtered_gis_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM gis_table
    WHERE /* some latlong filter */
)
SELECT *
FROM filtered_gis_table
ORDER BY price
```

But this is a local trick that you should use with caution, too many optimisation fences will make your application less future-friendly.